# Kendo Toolbar Get state of button and reset to load state

Tags: kendo-ui

I have two question I can't find the answers to;

Based on the following:

```
            $("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({

                            items: [

                                {
                                    type: "buttonGroup",
                                    

        id: "FilterControls",
                                buttons: [
                                    { id: "const", text: "Construction", spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-funnel", togglable: true, group: "filter", toggle: filterToggleHandler},
                                    

    { id: "lease", text: "Leasing", spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-funnel", togglable: true, group: "filter", toggle: filterToggleHandler },
                                { id: "legal", text: "Legal", spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-funnel", togglable: true, group: "filter", toggle: filterToggleHandler },
                                { id: "propt", text: "Property Management", spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-funnel", togglable: true, group: "filter", toggle: filterToggleHandler }
                            ]
                        

},
                     
                    { id: "mygreens", type: "button", text: "My Greens", spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-funnel", togglable: true, toggle: myToggleHandler },
                    { id: "clear", type: "button", text: "Clear", icon: "funnel-clear", click: filtClearall, togglable: false },
                    { is: "close", type: "button", text: "Close", spriteCssClass: "k-icon k-i-close", click: retOzone, togglable: false },
                ],
            });
```

First how from the toggle event of the filter group can I tell the state of the mygreens toogle button

and secondly how do I reset the toolbar back to its initial state with no buttons selected, based on the button clear click
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

```
var myGreensFilterActive = $('#mygreens').hasClass('k-state-active');
```

Second question:

```
filtClearall = function(){
          $('#FilterControls>a.k-state-active').removeClass('k-state-active');
            //remove filters from data source logic
           datasource.filter([]);    
          };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped me out